# wrong code jquery

Tags: jquery, delay, mouseover, mouseout

So I'm have an animated gif on `.mouseout` and `.mouseover` and after 3 seconds I want to have a still image there. The method I'm using is to change the `background-image` of the `div`, so I have four images:

1. when the page is loaded (i'm doing this in normal css file)
2. when mouse is over (should be animated and i'm doing this jQuery)
3. when mouse is out (should be animated and i'm doing this jQuery)
4. 3 seconds after the mouseout event (should be normal)

I am stuck on 4 and don't know how to write the code, so here is what I have for 2 and 3:

```
    $("#ubBackground").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().css("background-image","url(img/userBoxMouseOver.gif)");},
            function(){
      $('#ubBackground').css('background-image','url(img/userBoxMouseOut.gif)');
                        }
    );
```

I think I should use `.delay()` but I don't know exactly how, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var timer;

$("#ubBackground").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).css("background-image","url(img/userBoxMouseOver.gif)");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        var self=this;
        $(this).css('background-image','url(img/userBoxMouseOut.gif)');
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).css('background-image','url(img/userBox3secLater.gif)');
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Set a timer when the mouse leaves that changes the background after three seconds, and clear the timout in mouseenter in case the mouse enters again within the three seconds.

Comment: and again that looks very nice but when i put it in my jQuery file it stops working at all ?

Comment: Are you using jQuery version 1.7 or newer, and did you remember the document.ready wrapping.

Comment: eventually i was using some old version and now when i downloaded the newest it worked thanks a lot guys

Comment: Feel free to remember to accept the answer if it helped you out.